# Unable to record using OBS Multiplatform

Tags: screen, recorder

While I am trying to record OBS screen recorder getting a blank screen. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

What sources have you added? You need to add a display source to record the whole screen. The OBS windows will obviously be present in your video until you minimise it. If you want to record a single programme you can use the window source.